# MeteorJS get data passed to the template

Tags: templates, meteor, parameters, get, click

I am a newbie in MeteorJS. I tried to do list with download and report buttons:

List template:

```
<template name="myBooks">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>My books</h2>
        <div class="list-group">
            {{#each myBooks}} {{> myBookListItem}} {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

myBookListItem Template:

```
<template name="myBookListItem">
    <a class="list-group-item">
        <span class="badge badge-success">{{downloads}}</span>
        <span class="badge badge-error">{{warnings}}</span>

        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading "><i>{{title}}</i> - {{author}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text ">{{description}}</p>
        <button type="submit" id="download" class="btn btn-success">Download</button>
        <button type="submit" id="report" class="btn btn-danger">Report</button>
    </a>
</template>
```

My book collection item contains also "link" property which is url to downloadable pdf - how can I access it on #download button click?

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.myBookListItem.events({
        'click #download': function (event) {
            //What_kind_of_magic_shoud_i_use_here()
            alert();
        },
        'click #report': function (event) {
            alert();
        },

    });
}
```

Anybody can help me:)?

Comment: ok that was stupid, just had to use "this.link" :D

Comment: you may want to add that as an answer, so others can see that your question is no longer in need for an answer. And yes, it is OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to use `this.link`.